# How to choose a cell of a column from multiple columns in Excel sheet

Tags: excel, random, sampling

I was wondering if somebody knows How to choose a cell of a column from multiple columns in Excel sheet?
example :

A B C
0 1 2

I want a number to be selected randomly between (0-2)
Thanks

Comment: random as in return a1, b1, c1, or any permutation of {a,b,c}{0,1,2}

Answer (score 2):

> I want a number to be selected randomly between (0-2)

If you are looking for an Excel formula then you can use

```
=RANDBETWEEN(0,2)
```

If you are trying combinations from `A1 to C2` then you can try this. Omitting `0` as there is no cell range which is `A0`, `B0`, `C0`

```
=CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,67)) & RANDBETWEEN(1,2)
```

This formula will give you results from `A1`, `A2`, `B1`, `B2`, `C1`, `C2`

Comment: and wrap the second one in the indirect function to get a real cell reference (if he needs one). by the way, nice clean answer @SiddharthRout as someone who is a TA for a Business Excel course I appreciate concise solutions! (+1 for you)

Answer (score 0):

=RAND() * (b−a) + a does randomization, as does =RANDBETWEEN(a,b)

The other thing you would need is =CONCATENATE( text1, text2, ... text255 )

so, what you would do is be like =concatenate('a',randbetween(0,2))  would get you a random cell in the A column.  If it was cross the columns, do that for b, c.  If it is random letters 2, i need to look a bit more.

YOu just need to select that cell now.  Im sure there is a way to access that cell from that contents.  I am looking up http://excel.bigresource.com/Choose-Return-Cell-Based-On-Text-In-Another-JQVjkhos.html#oYwiAspH  and will edit in a second.

Answer (score 0):

Generically to select a cell randomly from any range you can use this formula

`=INDEX(range,ROWS(range)*RAND()+1,COLUMNS(range)*RAND()+1)`

that will work for any size contiguous range